# Prevent Creation of "System Volume Information"-folder for Specific Partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, shared-folders, partition-recovery

I have a NTFS-partition that is shared with my Linux installtion. When i'm on Windows, it doesn't bother me that the folder is there because i don't see it. However, that's not the case on Windows.

I found numerous pages that describe how to disable this feature on detachable drives, but not for a specific partition on the same drive.

Can someone help me figure this out or guide me to some documentation?

Comment: "Windows stores important system data here, and you should leave the folder alone." https://www.howtogeek.com/282214/WHAT-IS-THE-SYSTEM-VOLUME-INFORMATION-FOLDER-AND-CAN-I-DELETE-IT/ . That said, if it is large, just turn off System Restore on Windows for that drive. If you make regular images, that feature is fairly useless, anyway.

Comment: To quote the same page: "Just disabling System Protection for a drive won’t actually delete the System Volume Information folder. Windows stores more than just restore points here.", so basically System Restore is already disabled for the folder but i still see this folder popping up everytime i delete it. Is there nothing i can do about that?

Comment: Switch to ext4 or another file system. Windows *can* use ext4, with third-party tools.

Comment: Can you recommend a tool? Is there some utility i can use to mount ext4 in Windows?

Comment: There are many... just search online for "ext4 windows". My choice, when using a *primary partition*, is to open it read-only in DiskGenius.